# Regex for js variable end with semicolon

Tags: javascript, python, regex, beautifulsoup, regex-group

I am trying to find and extract an assignment of a property of the `product_image` object from Javascript code, extracted with BeautifulSoup. I have tried following

```
re.findall(r"product_images\['top_lg'] = .*;", txt)
```

Unfortunately it does not extract anything from my text below.

```
 product_images['top_lg'] = {
                "tn": '//image.test.com/media/cache/04/0a/040a1e61f5edc387d8c8e40d3ea0e0ca.jpg',
                "md": '//image.test.com/media/cache/b7/f3/b7f3cb1da267d7e8ac0412bdc522c862.jpg',
                "lg": '//image.test.com/media/shape_images/011f7f24ae4cbbef191cff1a711df9e1_a3c9ca71b7d85d87085955f8d1c4bfc3_0_.jpg',
                "alt": 'test ',
                "data-zoomable": 'True',
                "text_line": 'teest'
            };
```

The scripts that I am parsing are taken from https://www.brilliantearth.com/Petite-Twisted-Vine-Diamond-Ring-White-Gold-BE1D54-3821855/

Comment: just suggest how to get this whole variable using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, like me, you find regex flags confusing and hard to remember, use 
"not semicolon" expressions instead of dot

`re.findall(r"product_images\['top_lg'] = [^;]*;", txt)`

*Note*. Otherwise you can add a flag as Thierry suggests, though you would need also add a 'non-gready modifier' `?` after * to indicate that you are interested in the first semicolon rather that the last.

Comment: That's not what MULTILINE is for, have a look at [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE). The problem here is that `.` in `.*` won't match newlines. The option for this is `re.S`/`re.DOTALL`, see my answer for a working example.

Comment: thanks, addressed, though why I do not see your answer? Have you retracted it for some reason?